# $\int t^2\cos(1-t^3)\,dt$ Explanation

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I am trying to prep for a midterm.

One of my practice problems is this
$$\int t^2\cos(1-t^3)\,dt $$

Can someone show and explain how to do problems like these

Comment: I assume the integral is indefinite.

Comment: It is indefinite

Comment: There is an expression for an antiderivative in terms of the Fresnel integral, but there is no *elementary function* whose derivative is $\cos(1-t^2)$.

Comment: Sorry my formula is wrong i miss typed it

Comment: This should be just a basic substitution.  Nothing complicated here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $u=1-t^3$. Then what is $du$?

Comment: I like hints :)

Comment: $du = -3u^2$ is that right

Comment: Careful... you need $dt$ since you first differentiate $u = 1 - t^3$ with respect to $t$, giving us $\dfrac{du}{dt} = -3t^2$.  So we have $du = -3t^2\,dt$

Comment: just saw that mistake

Comment: the final answer is $\frac{-sin(1-t^3)}{3}$?

Comment: Looks right to me, @wolfcall